# Routing issue on application for root url in development / production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a problem on my application concerning routing. In production the root url is `example.com/xyz/`

And a lot of images_paths are set to `../xyz/assets/header.jpg`

In development I am receiving routing errors, since my host is `localhost:3000`. What I am trying to achieve is something like `localhost:3000/xyz` so the routing paths fit again. Production routes should stay the same.

Current error message in development environment is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/xyz/assets/header.jpg"):
```

Cant I use something like this in my application_controller?

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000/xyz'
```

Thx for advise

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a file path with something like,

```
@header_image_file = File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'xyz', 'assets', 'header.jpg')
```

Actually, RAILS_ROOT is deprecated since Rails 3, so you should now use,

```
@header_image_file = File.join(Rails.root.to_s, 'xyz', 'assets', 'header.jpg')
```

Good luck!

Comment: This answer is a response to the original question asked, prior to the question being edited.    @DannyRe - It looks like you've been around on SO long enough to know that this site won't work if you go back and change the question once you've got an answer.